# Gradle uploadArchives from Travis mangles staging repositories

Tags: gradle, travis-ci, sonatype, maven-central

I have an [open source project](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas) that [hooks to travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org/osmlab/atlas) and that builds with gradle.

This project uses the **gradle maven plugin** to upload release artifacts to [oss.sonatype.org](https://oss.sonatype.org/) using the **uploadArchives** target. What usually happens is that this target creates a single staging repository in Sonatype, then the [Gradle nexus staging plugin](https://github.com/Codearte/gradle-nexus-staging-plugin) promotes the repository and it shows up in Maven Central a few minutes later.

However, recently, the **uploadArchives** target started creating multiple staging repositories, each with a partial subset of the artifacts needed; and that happens only when run in Travis, not when I try from a laptop.

[image: Repository list]

What am I missing here, which makes it work locally when running `./gradlew uploadArchives`, but fail in Travis?

A few links which might help:

- [Github issue, with screenshots](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas/issues/242)
- [Travis deploy script](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas/blob/c8bbfb67de67973fbf4a247b43ba734ca179afea/.travis/deploy.sh)
- [Failed Travis build](https://travis-ci.org/osmlab/atlas/builds/440233428)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it appears [this is a common error that started appearing this year](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/9555). Travis VMs with `sudo: enabled` or docker will change IP addresses between artifact uploads and this will prompt Sonatype to think those artifacts belong to different repositories. Adding this to my `travis.yml` fixed it:

```
sudo: false
dist: trusty
```